# D3 plotting categorical data with a range(min, max) value using points and line

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

I have a dataset that has 3 fields a name, a min value (`value2`) and a max value (`value`) that represent a range.

```
//The data
var data =[{"name": 'Scotty', "value2":0, "value":17},
 {"name":'Dick', "value2":10, "value":17},
 {"name":'James', "value2":5, "value":null},
 {"name":'Max', "value2":2, "value":9}]
```

Currently I have it represented with a bar chart using this code that works ok except in cases where the points value2 and value are very close or there is a null value.

```
//Chart size parameters
var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 90, left: 40},
    width = 830 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

//Chart axis
var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.name; }))
    .range([2, width])
    .scaleBand(0.10);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })])
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

//Initialize chart
var chart = d3.select("#mychart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  //Adding both axis
  chart.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)

  chart.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);

 //Where the box is drawn
  chart.selectAll(".box")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "box")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.name); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.value2) - y(d.value); })  //Plot range
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth()); //spacing for bars
```

Is there a way to plot the data with the following:

- if two points are present plot both of them with a path connecting them
- if one point is present with a null in field `value` only plot the one point

Comment: add `paddingInner` to your `scaleBand` so you don't have to use the `*0.9`

Comment: split your data (`filter`) on the test of both present and create a draw for each that represent how you want to see it.

Comment: @rioV8 ok done, not sure about the filter thing but I just want a line representing the range and if it is a single value with null as the second value a dot or something can be used so that the point can be seen.